# Is it possible to integrate IBM RTC Advisor fields to JAXB

Tags: rtc, extensibility, jazz, ibm-jazz

I'm working on IBM RTC Advisors, based on a Workshop provided in http://jazz.net.

Now I´m trying to port the xsd document provided in their OSGi module to annotations+jaxb.

That´s part of the XSD:

```
<xsd:element name="followup-action" substitutionGroup="process:followup-action"
    type="buildOnStateChangeType"/>

<xsd:complexType name="buildOnStateChangeType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            This type defines the build on state change type. It is a
            subtype of the abstract process:followupActionType. This
            restriction, along with the substitutionGroup specification
            above, makes it possible to add configuration of the participant
            to a project or team area's process configuration. Note the
            forward references to the trigger and build types defined below.
            Take particular note of the id attribute. It is required and has
            a fixed value that points to our operation participant extension.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="process:followupActionType">
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="trigger" type="triggerType"
                    minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="build" type="buildType" minOccurs="1"
                    maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:all>
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required"
                fixed="net.jazz.rtcext.workitem.extensions.service.buildOnStateChange"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="triggerType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            This type defines the work item type to be monitored
            and the work item state that should trigger the
            operation participant.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="changed-workitem-type" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"
                    use="required"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="trigger-state" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"
                    use="required"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="buildType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            This type defines the build to run. At this point, it just
            includes the build definition id. In the future, it could
            include more information, for example, a list of properties
            to pass to the build.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="build-definition" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"
                    use="required"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And this is part of the XML from process template:

```
<followup-action
    xmlns="http://net.jazz.rtcext.workitem.extensions.service/server/buildOnStateChange"
    description="When the specified work item type changes to the specified state, the
    specified build will be requested."
    id="net.jazz.rtcext.workitem.extensions.service.buildOnStateChange"
    name="Build on State Change">
    <trigger>
        <changed-workitem-type id="com.ibm.team.apt.workItemType.story"/>
        <trigger-state id="com.ibm.team.apt.story.tested"/>
    </trigger>
    <build>
        <build-definition id="our.integration.build.bogus"/>
    </build>
</followup-action>
```

My problem is, how is the best way to port that XSD, to Java Classes with JAXB annotations? I tried reverse engineering using Eclipse (Luna) JAXB support.

Source: https://jazz.net/library/article/1000

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment yet........

Why do you want to do what you describe above? The data described by the XSD is stored in the process configuration and there is a set of API available to access the data from within the extension.

Comment: I'm trying to use annotations instead of a static XSD.